# Typescript AngularJS service doesn't work on WebDeploy to Azure

Tags: angularjs, azure, typescript

I have a problem with a AngularJS service Written in typescript.
When I use Visual Studios WebDeply to Publish my app to a Azure Webserver I get an error telling me that

> Error: Unknown provider: localeServiceProvider <- localeService

When I publish this on my local machine it works fine. The only difference that I have been able to find is that on my local machine the app loads the .js files, while on the Azure server it loads the .js.map files. And I'm thinking that this might be the problem. The service (.js) that is referenced on the local machine looks like this:

```
/// <reference path='../_all.ts' />
var blackbird;
(function (blackbird) {
    'use strict';

    /**
    * Services that persists and retrieves localized strings from Web Api.
    */
    var LocaleService = (function () {
        function LocaleService($http, $log) {
            this.$http = $http;
            this.$log = $log;
        }
        LocaleService.prototype.injection = function () {
            return [
                '$http',
                '$log',
                LocaleService
            ];
        };

        LocaleService.prototype.get = function (successcb) {
            this.$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/locales' }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                successcb(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                this.$log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
            });
        };
        return LocaleService;
    })();
    blackbird.LocaleService = LocaleService;
})(blackbird || (blackbird = {}));
```

And the service (.js) that is referenced on the Azure server looks like this:

```
/// <reference path='../_all.ts' />
var blackbird;
(function (blackbird) {
    'use strict';

    /**
    * Services that persists and retrieves localized strings from Web Api.
    */
    var LocaleService = (function () {
        function LocaleService($http, $log) {
            this.$http = $http;
            this.$log = $log;
        }
        LocaleService.prototype.injection = function () {
            return [
                '$http',
                '$log',
                LocaleService
            ];
        };

        LocaleService.prototype.get = function (successcb) {
            this.$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/locales' }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                successcb(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                this.$log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
            });
        };
        return LocaleService;
    })();
    blackbird.LocaleService = LocaleService;
})(blackbird || (blackbird = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=LocaleService.js.map
```

As far as I can tell they look pretty much identical apart from

> //# sourceMappingURL=LocaleService.js.map

Earlier I added the js.map files to the project to make sure they where uploaded to the server, as they where not by default and when publishing the app gave errors asking for them.
Anyone got any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when you main angular app module starts before the browser has downloaded the service script. Make sure that the `LocaleService` is loaded by the browser before you create your main app module.

This is assuming that the `LocaleService.js` is available after deployment (which seems to be the case as you can see if). If not make sure the `js` file is added to your visual studio project.